# Android Firebase realtime database filter parents

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a basic sports statistics Android app using Firebase and I'm not sure how to filter the database base when reading. My database is structured like below, how would I filter a search so I only get parents who contain children of `team1:redsox` and `team2:yankees` while ignoring game3?

Database image:

[image: Database image here]

Comment: Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. You could for example add a property `"teams": "red sox_yankees"` and then filter on that. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `game1`, `game2` and `game3` nodes are direct children of your Firebase database root, to solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String team1 = ds.child("team1").getValue(String.class);
            String team2 = ds.child("team2").getValue(String.class);
            if(team1.equals("redsox") && team2.equals("yankees")) {
                Log.d("TAG", "Foaund only: team1:redsox and team2:yankees");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

But note, team1 in game1 is `red sox` (two words) and in the game2 is `redsox` (single word). In order to make the `equals()` method work, both properties should hold the same value, either `red sox` or `redsox`.

Comment: Have you tried my solution above, does it work?